# Find parameters such that $f(z)=\log(x^2+y^2)-a(\arg z)^2+ib\arg\bar z+\dfrac{c}{\bar z}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

The problem asks you for what values of $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ you can find a domain in $\mathbb C$ where
$$f(z)=\log(x^2+y^2)-a(\arg z)^2+ib\arg\bar z+\dfrac{c}{\bar z}$$
is analytic.

Due to the nature of the function, it is most preferable to work in polar coordinates:
$$f(z)=2\log r-a\theta^2-ib\theta+\dfrac{c}{r}e^{i\theta}.$$

We now impose that it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann in polars for the function to be analytic; namely,
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\dfrac{1}{ir}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}.$$

In brief, doing the operations I get
$$\dfrac{2}{r}-\dfrac{c}{r^2}e^{i\theta}=i\dfrac{2a\theta}{r}-\dfrac{b}{r}+\dfrac{c}{r^2}e^{i\theta}.$$

Finally, comparing both real and imaginary parts, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\mathfrak{Re}: \dfrac{2+b}{r}=\dfrac{2c}{r^2}\cos\theta\\
&\mathfrak{Im}: \dfrac{2a\theta}{r}=-\dfrac{2c}{r^2}\sin\theta . 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Solutions says $a,c=0$ and $b=-2$. How can I deduce this from the previous system of equations if it'd have $1$ degree of freedom?

Comment: The system must be true for infinitely many values of $r$ and $\theta$. I remember so.

Comment: I'm guessing that the parameters can't vary with $r$ and $\theta$ so they have to be constant and make those eqs. true for any value of $r$ and $\theta$. The only solution that satisfies this is the one mentioned at the end then, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. To be precise, the equations don't have to be true for _every_ $r$, $\theta$, just for $r$, $\theta$ on some open set. But that's enough to constrain the values of $a$, $b$, $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log z^2 = \log |z|^2 + i \arg z^2 = \log (x^2+y^2)+ 2i \arg z. $$

This, the polar form, and the compact form of the Cauchy Riemann equations:  $$\frac{df}{d\overline{z}}=0$$ (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html)

yields:  $$b=-2, a=c=0.$$

The domain is $$\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}.$$

Comment: I solved it using $f(z,\bar z)$ too, but looks like I can't solve it with polars.

Comment: The polar form of the C-R equations imply that $f(z)$ contains a term $ -2 i a \theta \log r$, and thus $a=0.$

Comment: Thank you and the people who commented; I think I solved my doubt. Also, thanks for noting the domain of analycity, I forgot about it.

Comment: As noted, $a=0$ because there is no term involving $\theta \log r$, and $c=0$ because we must have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$.   The term involving $\arg \overline{z}$ can be rewritten $- i b \arg z$ and $b$ is chosen appropriately to satisfy the C-R equations.